# ant java tag to use myown version java.exe

Tags: java, ant

I have different **jdk** available. I tried the **ant javac**'s `executable` and `fork` attributes to ask ant use a particular **javac.exe** to compile the code. But cannot find a way for **ant java** tag to use particular **java.exe**.

I tried the `dir` and `fork` attributes. It seems not a right way to do.

Do you have any way to make ant use the **java.exe** I want to which is not the same as the one from the system? I am using windows 7.

**EDIT:**

I searched online and cannot understand why ant doesn't provide an easy way to do this?

Comment: `dir` is where the JVM will start up; it has nothing to do with the JVM being used. The `jvm` attribute is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of the java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) shows how to do it, using the `jvm` attribute:

```
<java classname="ShowJavaVersion" 
      classpath="."
      jvm="path-to-java14-home/bin/java" 
      fork="true"
      taskname="java1.4">
```

> Use a given Java implementation (another the one Ant is currently using) to run the class. For documentation in the log taskname is used to change the [java] log-prefix to [java1.4]

Comment: I actually tried that jvm, it seems not for this purpose. I will try again anyway.

Comment: Given what is written in the doc right after the example (and that I added to the answer), it really seems to be for this purpose.

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA What's the evidence for thinking it isn't the correct option? I'm almost positive it is, although I can't test at the moment.

Comment: My fault. After test again, I found it is the right way to go. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [Ant Exec Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) the arguments for it were a bit tricky last time I used it, you might need to experiment with the various ways arguments can be passed as well as the various other JVM arguments to get the bootclasspath correct.